# setcurrenttab from preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

The default tab that is displayed in my app is tab 0. I would like when Preference uso is clicked, to change the currentTab to 1, as well as the next time the app opens, tab 1 is displayed instead of tab 0.

This is the Preferences.java contents:

```
package com.fbisoft.uowt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

      getPreferenceManager().findPreference("uso").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            TabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
            return true;
         }
      });
   }
}
```

The `TabHost.setCurrentTab(1);` gives me an error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setCurrentTab(int)
from the type TabHost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your activity that has the `TabHost` watch for preference changes, then change your tab there. You cannot tell the `TabHost` class to change a tab.